# How to let Drupal use two databases

Tags: 7, users

I want to use an admin specific page to insert or remove new users, instead of using the Drupal administration panel.

How can I prescind from the Drupal default database and insert the users' information in my personal database? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

In drupal 7 you can easily connect to 2 or more different databases.
From your question I guess you have a module to handle the users rather than the normal Drupal Way. So you can follow the following,

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>  // main drupal db starts from here
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupaldb', // main drupal db name
      'username' => 'root', // main drupal db username
      'password' => 'password', // main drupal db password
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),'yourcustomdb' =>  // additional database starts here
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'database', // additional database name
      'username' => 'root', // additional database username
      'password' => 'password', // additional database password
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    )
  ),
);
```

Then in time of calling it,

```
db_set_active('yourcustomdb');
$query = db_query('....');
db_set_active('default'); // We need to call the main (drupal) db back
```

I hope this one helps you.

Comment: I thank you for the answer: it is very useful! But I am using the default drupal module: It should be "User". Can you suggest me a module to manage users?

Comment: I guess there is no other modules rather than Users module from Drupal Core. But google can help you I guess.

Comment: One important thing to note about this, is that the databases need to be of the same type for this to work. You can't do this on a mysql/pgsql setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Web Services module, it will allow you to make remote calls using a REST server you setup and administer it remotely.

EG: 
yourdomain.com/rest/user/create