# Empty space on top of the page

Tags: 7

I coded some modules (basically only PHP and no alter of Drupal functions), and on mysterious way, two of my modules are producing an empty quote on top of my meta tags in the body.
This causes a 20 empty pixels on top of my page, and destroys my slider.

As mentioned, two modules are producing this; I figured out that the first module produces this when I use `include_once("config/rewards.inc");`. If I comment it out, everything works fine. 
`include_once("config/rewards.inc");` is already included in one of my other modules, but I used `include_once`, to include it, obviously, only once.
`include_once("config/config.inc");` doesn't produce this error.

This is a screenshot of Firebug (the arrow point at the margin).

[image: screenshot]

In my first module, the problem happens when I uncomment the line containing `require_once("config/rewards.inc")`.

```
<?php 
//      *****************************************
//      **      Donate Script for Trinity      **
//      **             by Leandros         **
//      *****************************************


//module_load_include('inc', 'donatescript', 'rewards');
//module_load_include('inc', 'donatescript', 'config');
require_once("config.inc");
//Produce problems (for some reason I dont know ^^)
//require_once("config/rewards.inc");

if(user_is_logged_in()){
global $user;
global $donatepoints;
$userip = $user->hostname;
$userid = $user->uid;
$username = $user->name;
$usernameuc = strtoupper($user->name);


//$GLOBALS['reward_items'] = $tab_rewards;
//$GLOBALS['reward_texts'] = $reward_texts;

//Get Variables from config.inc for realmd DB
$db = $realmd_DB['1']['3'];
$host = $realmd_DB['1']['0'];
$dbuser = $realmd_DB['1']['1'];
$dbpassword = $realmd_DB['1']['2'];

//Connect to realmd DB
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db, $connect) or die (mysql_error());

//query overall donatepoint value
$donate_points_select = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM donate_points WHERE id='$userid'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($donate_points_select)) {
    $donatepoints = $row['points'];
}

if($donatepoints == 0) {
    $GLOBALS['donatepoints'] = 0;
} else {
    $GLOBALS['donatepoints'] = $donatepoints;
}

//mysql_query("INSERT INTO `donate_points` (`id`, `name`, `points`) VALUES ('$userid', '$usernameuc', '$donatepoints')");

//Close DB connection
mysql_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to point out that you can [tell Drupal to manage your second database connection](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31325/how-to-let-drupal-use-two-databases) as well, and thus integrate your code in a nice fashion with Drupal.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: Not directly, no. I'm just observing that by removing things like custom error handling and globals, you can clean up and shorten down the code, which reduces the general risk of problem.

Comment: I just observed, that the `require_once("config/rewards.inc");` generate that empty quote even if the file is empty ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error in the second module: It was because the opening `<?php` tag had a tab before it.

I fixed the second module, too. I don't know which produced the empty space, but I created for every file I used a new file and pasted my code into, renamed the module and enabled it. Everything now works.

Comment: Sometimes editors insert the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file. That could be interpreted as [zero-width non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-breaking_space).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is better practice (in Drupal) to use this in your .module file

```
/**
* Includes necessary files for YOUR_MODULE_NAME module 
*/
module_load_include('inc', 'MODULE_NAME', 'rewards');
module_load_include('inc', 'MODULE_NAME', 'config');

//you don't need the trailing .inc in rewards as drupal adds it in this function.
```

This will allow you to load the file only once (using require_once see [module_load_include](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) ).

So, try this 'Drupal Way' instead of include_once.  If that still gives you the weirdness with the extra space, perhaps post the code of rewards.inc (unless it contains sensitive info, which should be redacted).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the include doesn't work on this way, my module use db credentials from config which can't be read with `module_load_include`

Comment: Ok, well then perhaps try require_once and if that does work post your code (with the caveats as noted above).

Comment: require_once doesn't work. I'll include my code, wait a minute. They're 3 modules, but only 2 modules are causing problems (good news: this biggest don't cause the problems).

Comment: Code is in the main issue post. THanks for helping!